# Microsoft Outlook Inbox Repair Tool - Not Responding

Tags: microsoft-outlook

We are running the Microsoft Outlook Inbox Repair Tool. After doing its diagnostics, we click `Repair`, at which point the program goes into Not Responding status.

[image]

We've tried leaving it for five minutes. We've also ensured that all Outlook and email related processes are stopped in the Task Manager. Why doesn't the tool work? How can we make it work?

Comment: You don't.  I suspect the reason its doing this is because of the errors it found were not minor.

Comment: How does the same task appear in the resource monitor?  is there any slow disk actvity on that process? any cpu use high on (at least) a single core? Not-responding does not always mean "not working", it does mean the program is not returning in a speedy way, and tasks deemed to be not responding are backgrounded (from what i can tell) to keep them from locking up the machine.  This makes it even slower for them to accomplish tasks that are not working well.

Answer (score 3):

"Not Responding" does not always, or even most of the time, mean that the program is failing.

It simply means the program is too busy to respond to the OS asking what's going on. Windows periodically asks a program to respond to it to make sure it's still functioning properly. If a program is particularly busy it may not be able to respond to Windows' query. It happens. It usually doesn't mean anything.

Your Inbox Repair Tool is probably very busy at the moment repairing your PST file. In my experience, based on the size of the PST and the nature of the issues, this repair process can take hours.

So be patient.

It's possible the issues may be too much for the tool as alancc notes, but 5 minutes is not nearly enough time to know that.

Comment: In my experience, if a PST was greater than 2GB, it either took awhile in an attempt to repair or just did not repair it all.